# Como converter um array de string string[] para um array de inteiros int[]

Tags: c#, conversão

Qual é uma forma simples para converter um array de string[] para um array de inteiros[]

```
string[] arrayString = new string[] {"10", "20", "30"}
```

Para:

```
int[] arrayInt = new int[] {10, 20, 30}
```

Comment: Você pode garantir que todos os dados são válidos? De onde eles estão vindo?

Comment: @Maniero Essa informações de onde essas informações de onde os dados vem e se são válidos são relevantes ? Pois no meu cenário os dados vinham de uma base legada e sim eram válidos.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma simples de fazer essa conversão é:

```
 string[] arrayString = new string[] {"10", "20", "30"};
 int[] arrayInt = arrayString.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Ou

```
 int[] arrayInt = arrayString.Select(lnq => int.Parse(lnq)).ToArray();
```

E desta forma também fica possível realizar a conversão não somente para `int`, mas também para `decimal`, `double` etc ...

Basta apenas alterar dentro do select "int.Parse" para o tipo que você deseja converter.

Comment: Eu sei que a pergunta é sua e a resposta funcionou para o seu caso, mas se o array de String tiver letras além de números dará uma exceção. O correto é utilizar um `tryParse`

Comment: @Focos Concordo com você apenas quis exemplificar o caso aonde eu tenho um array de string no quais os valores do array são números e quero converte-los para para um respectivo array numérico (int, double etc).
Mas caso dentro do array de string contenha letras e afins. Essa abordagem a cima tem que ser modificada.

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer assim:

```
int[] arrayInt1 = Array.ConvertAll(arrayString, x => int.Parse(x));
```

Ou assim:

```
int[] arrayInt1 = Array.ConvertAll(arrayString, int.Parse);
```

Comment: O que isto é diferente da resposta já postada?

Comment: O método estático Array.ConvertAll

Comment: [Malandro é o cavalo marinho que mora embaixo d'água pra não puxar carroça](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/387771/revisions)

Comment: Fiz algo errado no fim das contas? Ao meu ver foi apenas uma resposta complementar. Contudo, vou dar uma verificada nas regras para evitar respostas que não estejam adequadas.